# fetching value from list on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search box which gives me options to select from. For ex: when i type 'p' in the search box i get a list saying 
personA
personB
personC

Now,when i click on personB, i want to capture the value as "personB". However, in my code no matter what i click on the value captured is always "personA". Here is the code written on my jsp page.

```
    <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"
></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#keywords").keyup(function() {
            var kw = $("#keywords").val();
            if (kw.length != 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type : "GET",
                    url : "getPerson.jsp",
                    contentType : "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    dataType : "json",
                    data : {
                        "searchBoxText" : kw
                    },
                    success : function(response)
                    {
                        var htmlToShow = '<ul>';
                        $.each(response, function(personId, personName)
                                  {
                            htmlToShow += '<li>ID: ' + personId + "; Name: " + personName + '</li>';
                                  })
                                  htmlToShow += '</ul>'
                                  $("#results").html(htmlToShow);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $("#results").html("");
            }
            return false;
        });
        $("#results").click(function() {

            alert($('li').html());  
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="Logout.jsp">Logout</a>
    <center>
        <div class="ajax_body">
            <div id="inputbox">
                <input
                    id="keywords"
                    type="text"
                    name="keywords"
                    value=""
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="results"></div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>

    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#results").click(function(e) {
    alert($(e.target).html());  
});
```

Comment: Brilliant.. ! I'll get back if any other doubts :)

Comment: So i just wrote down this sql query and i am trying to capture the value of rest_id in query.list() . However, this is giving the value as [1] . I want just 1 without the braces. How do i do it? The code is as follows:        String sql1 = "select rest_id from rest_details where rest_name = '" + nameclicked + "' and rest_location = '" +locclicked + "'" ;
    SQLQuery query1 = session.createSQLQuery(sql1);
    System.out.println("sql1 " + query1.list());

Comment: @user2791805 sorry man, I never heard about that `createSQLQuery` function. Don't know how it works. I suggest you to ask another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want to do is something like this:

```
$("#results").on("click", "li", function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

This allows you to bind a *delegated* handler to the parent item that will allow you to have click handlers for dynamically added DOM elements.

Comment: So i just wrote down this sql query and i am trying to capture the value of rest_id in query.list() . However, this is giving the value as [1] . I want just 1 without the braces. How do i do it? The code is as follows: String sql1 = "select rest_id from rest_details where rest_name = '" + nameclicked + "' and rest_location = '" +locclicked + "'" ; SQLQuery query1 = session.createSQLQuery(sql1); System.out.println("sql1 " + query1.list());

Comment: @user2791805: That sounds like a separate question. Don't ask more questions in the comments, create a new question and you'll get answers.